# How do I get an instance of a Grails service programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, grails

I have an external data source, which will return a string indicating the name of a Grails service to use.

What's the syntax to get an instance of this service programatically given the name of the service as a String?

ie. given 'GoogleWeather', give me an instance of GoogleWeatherService.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The Grails documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20100724145043/http://www.grails.org/Services) describes a way to get a service when in a servlet. This might be useful, if you can obtain the same objects in your context:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext();
CountryServiceInt service = (CountryServiceInt) ctx.getBean("countryService");
String str = service.sayHello(request.getParameter.("name"));
```

Answer (score 29):

Since ApplicationHolder has been deprecated, this is another way to get the ApplicationContext:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext
```

Comment: `(Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext as GenericApplicationContext).getBean("myService")`