# Grails: Prevent further code execution after a redirect or forward in base class of a controller

Tags: grails, redirect, controller, radix

I have following controller structure:

```java
abstract class AbstractController {
  // ...
}

abstract class AbstractDiagramController extends AbstractController {
  // ...
}

class PopulationController extends AbstractDiagramController {
  // ...
}
```

Most controller-actions call various methods of the abstract base classes. If now one of these base-methods needs to send a redirect (or forward) to the client, Grails won't prevent the application from processing the remaining action code of the controller-action anyway.

From my point of view this is an undesirable behaviour, due the base-methods do some kind of validation (like validating parameter, user, session etc), and the controller assumes that the validation succeeded (thence produces subsequent errors).

How can i prevent this insufficient behaviour?

Kind regards,
Christopher

PS: I found already [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805535/why-forward-and-redirect-in-grails-dont-stop-initial-action-execution), but the answers did not satisfy my needs, because none of them deal with a base controller:

PPS: I am using Grails in version 1.3.7

**EDIT**

This is a reaction of Victor Sergienko's comments.
Here I give a more detailled code-example of my problem.

```
// The very base controller
abstract class AbstractController { 

    // The interceptor gets called before any action of inheritors get processed
    def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&initialize]

    // Method validates various stuff
    protected initialize() {
        if( someThingIsWrong() ) {
            // This redirect should stop any other code of inheritors
            redirect( controller: "foo", action: "bar" )
            return false
        }
    } 
}

// The second base controller
abstract class AbstractDiagramController extends AbstractController { 

    // This object must get initialized. If not (eg any errors or exceptions occured) 
    // all inheritors actions are not allowed to do anything
    MyObject myGreatObject = null

    // Overriden, because of additional individual diagram validation
    @Override
    protected initialize() {
        // Do parents stuff first
        super.auth()

        // If parent failed, this code should not get executed anymore.
        // Yes, here I could check if parent returned false and return false as well before
        // continuing the next validation. Anyway I have to do this because grails, comprehendibly,
        // will throw an exception if two redirects were executed in a row.
        // (With this I just want to visualize the behaviour I'd expect)
        if( someThingElseIsWrong() ) { 
            redirect( controller: "hello", action: "world")
            return false
        }

        // After validation I can initialize the object
        myGreatObject = new MyObject()
    }
}


// A controller implementation
class MyDiagramController extends AbstractDiagramController {

    // Overriden because of inidividual validation
    @Override 
    protected initialize() {

        // First do parent stuff
        boolean succeeded = super.auth()

        // Again, annoying double check
        if( !succeeded ) {
            return false
        }
    }

    def myAction = { 
        myGreatObject.SpinAroundAndBeHappy()
    } 
}
```

Looks like it was a good idea to reduce the use-case to the minimum lines of code. Now it seem like Victor's suggestions (either `canContinue` or `hasErrors`) could solve this unpleasant circumstances somehow, even though it's some kind of workaround.

But somehow I don't like those double-checks. I'm still struggling against the fact, that all *layers* above the abstract base controller have to react on invalid validations that happened already before (and also should be managed by the base controllers on their own). From my point of view those checks should not be the business of the controller implementations.

PS: I hope no grave mistakes have slipped in the code.

Comment: have you tried to explicit set a return statement after the redirect or forward? maybe this will prevent the execution of the further code.

Comment: Yes, i tried this already. The result is that it returns to the inheritor directly, but it does not stop to continue to process the inheritors action code.

Comment: like you said, seems to be a misbehaviour.

Comment: Ja, unfortunately. I just created a ticket, don't know if it's realy a bug more then a an intended design rule. But I'll wait the reaction.
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7744

Comment: Did you mean `super.initialize()` instead of `super.auth()` or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can return a `boolean canContinue` from an ancestor action or throw an exception, or check `instance.hasErrors()` in your case.

**EDIT**: The fact `initialize()` is called **before** an action looks like access control or another complete override of action semantics (before any part of action is executed). Please tell if my assumption is wrong.

When we did a custom security access to different actions, we annotated the actions with own tags like `@SecuredDoodah` (see [@Secured](http://grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Basic+Tutorial+with+Annotations)), and added a `Filter` that completely overrides the action (for us, `Filter` responds with 403, but it's not necessary).

`Filter` might be better than `beforeInterceptor`. If you need to pass some state from `Filter`, like `myGreatObject` in the sample, you can [inject a Service into Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826354/can-i-inject-a-service-into-a-filter-in-grails) and save the state in the Service.

I'm sure there are better ways then my idea, but this should work transparently for Controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, there are some workarounds. But each workaround implies considerable changes to the code.
My example was a bit simplified, in real the problem does not occure inside the action directly, rather inside a method that gets called by the action method. Secondly I also work with beforeInterceptors.
And to change all occurances and calls will end in some unsatisfying results and redundant code. Because even if I use some kind of `canContinue` flag, then the inheritor must provide the same error handling/redirect as the base controller.

Comment: Ideal solution would just return from the middle of any action after a function call that invoked `redirect()` or `render()`, correct? I'm afraid it's impossible in Groovy. It cannot `return` from a calling function. You have to put at least SOME code around the function invocation anyway.

Comment: What is it about the error handling? It can be either fully done in ancestor, or you don't actually need to "prevent ...remaining action code". Can you expand the code sample a bit?

Comment: Hi Victor, please have a look at my edited posting, I attached a more detailled example. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I choosed your answer as the accepted one, but since I'm still a newbie on stackoverflow I can not vote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're limited by the fact that this is Java/Groovy and there's no way for a method call to immediately trigger an exit from a method (or Closure). I saw that another framework cheats and when you call render, redirect, etc. it throws an exception that's caught it the framework base class. This acts like a Goto, which doesn't really exist.

It's an expensive approach though - filling in all those stack frames unnecessarily is wasteful since it's not an exception case and the stack will always be ignored.

Unfortunately you need an approach like Victor's where you use boolean return values.

Comment: Hi Burt, thanks for your answer. I think then I will choose Victor's approach.
By the way, I recognized that my JIRA report was updated by Graeme Rocher, the summary now contains the exception approach.. maybe this is the only way to solve this kind of circumstance? (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7744?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel#issue-tabs).

Comment: We have discussed this approach in the past, and there's a way to create an exception without filling in the stack frames. We could cache that and use it in approach like this. But it probably won't make it into 2.0, especially since it might break existing apps that depend on the current behavior. But I think it's a good candidate for a release after 2.0.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. So until this behaviour is not changed I will build the controller structure as mentioned above.